# web2py multiple records in 1 form or in wizard

Tags: forms, web2py, wizard

In web2py, making a ticket reservation form

Simplified db view:

```
db.define_table('shows', Field('ShowName', 'string'))
db.define_table('reservations', 
                 Field('PersonName','string'),
                 Field('NbrOfTickets','integer'),
                 Field('show_id',db.shows))
db.reservations.show_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.shows.id, '%(ShowName)s')
```

When making a reservation:
People need to first fill their name, then select a show from a drop-down and amount of tickets.

All this works fine, BUT:
I want people to be able to make reservations for more than 1 show!
But people don't like to fill their name more than once...

**So the question is: how can I make a form (or wizard) which allows people to fill out only once their name, and then get the possibility to fill out several (amount unknown upfront) forms where they select 1 show + amount of tickets.**

If all this can be done without wizard, also fine for me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The following works: (thx for suggestion by Massimo Di Pierro)

Solution is to pre-populate the form, so that if the same user fills the form twice he doesn't have to re-enter his name:

```
def reserve():
    form  = SQLFORM(db.reservations)
    form.vars.PersonName = session.PersonName
    if form.process().accepted:
        session.PersonName = form.vars.PersonName
    return dict(form=form)
```